# Find common elements in two lines from two files

Tags: python

I have two tab-delimted big files,

```
1)Bmag0905  chr7B   401656584   401656568
Bmag0905    chr7A   459876086   459876070
Bmag0904    chr2B   472060312   472060296
Bmag0904    chr2A   373596126   373596110
Bmag0904    chr7B   401656584   401656568

2)Bmag0905  chr7B   172039378   172039358
Bmag0905    chr4B   186310411   186310431
Bmag0904    chr4B   532339252   532339232
Bmag0904    chr2B   708832397   708832377
Bmag0904    chr3A   673781330   673781350
```

I want to get elements which are common both in 1st and 2nd lines. So my output would be like this,

```
Bmag0905  chr7B   401656584   401656568 Bmag0905  chr7B   172039378   172039358
Bmag0904    chr2B   472060312   472060296 Bmag0904    chr2B   708832397   708832377
```

So, this is how I create a dictionary, now the question is how to find the common elements like above and print in a new file the desired lines? Also, should I group by element[0]?

```
fileA = open("input1.txt",'r')
fileB = open("input2.txt",'r')
output = open("shared",'w')
dictA = {}
for line1 in fileA:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    query=new_list[0]
    subject=new_list[1]
    dictA.setdefault((query), []).append(subject)
dictB = {}
for line1 in fileB:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    query=new_list[0]
    subject=new_list[1]
    dictB.setdefault((query), []).append(subject)
Shared ={}
for id1, value1 in dictA.items(): (?)
   if id1 in dictB.keys():(?)
```

Comment: avoid `if id1 in dictB.keys()`: do `if id1 in dictB`

Comment: Are you willing to use a Unix/Linux utility that already does this, or you need a Python solution?

Comment: I prefer a python solution...thanks..but you can mention which utility, I can have a look and learn anyway and I might find it more useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some `csv` and `set` based solution using pair of first two column values as keys. I take it from your sample in-/ouput that the commonness is based on te first two columns:

```
import csv

read_a = csv.reader(filaA, delimiter='\t')
read_b = csv.reader(filaB, delimiter='\t')

dict_a = {tuple(row[:2]): row for row in read_a}
dict_b = {tuple(row[:2]): row for row in read_b}

shared_keys = set(dict_a) & set(dict_b)  # intersection of keys

writer = csv.writer(open('file.csv', 'w'), delimiter='\t')
writer.writerows(dict_a[k] + dict_b[k] for k in shared_keys)
```

Comment: Thanks! A question: how this code is going to deal if I have i.e. Bmag0905  chr7B  repeated 2-3 times in both files (with lines[2] &[3] being different anyway?

Comment: Will only occur once in `dict_a/b`. How do you know which pairs to match?

Comment: I dont know...may be the solution could be to match all in cases like that? Also if I have Bmag0905 chr7B Bmag0905 chr7A in 1 file and in the second Bmag0905 chr7B Bmag0905 chr7A as well, it will print both, right? Sorry, just to understand the script